# Printing an array from lowest to highest without sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I want to start off by saying I am not very experienced and I am sorry if this has been answered. I have been trying to find an answer for a while and have not been able to.

I am working on a project where the user inputs numbers into an array. These numbers represent temperatures for different days. The days are obviously the position in the array. I need to find a way to print the temperatures from least to greatest without sorting the array.

So if the user entered [56, 45, 67, 41, 59, 70] that means that it was 56 degrees at position 0 (day 1), 67 degrees at position 2 (day 3). I need to keep the position of the array the same so the days remain with the temps when it prints out.

Edit: I have attached the code I have on my project so far. The HighestOrdered method is the method I dont know what to do or where to start. For the HighestOrdered method as I said above I need to have it print out the temps with the day (the position in the array) and I am not sure how to do that.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class Weather {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int [] high = new int[30];
    int [] low = new int[30];

    Init (high);
    Init(low);


    LoadData(high,low);
    Report(high, low);

    FindAvg(high,low);
    Lowest(high, low);
    Highest(high,low);
}
public static void Init(int A[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        A[i] = 510;
    }
}

public static void Report(int[] H, int[] L)
{
    System.out.println("Day    High    Low");

    for(int i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i + "      " + H[i] + "      " + L[i]);
    }
}
public static void LoadData(int[] H, int[] L)
{

    int day = 0;
    while(day < 30)
    {
        try {
            int high = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("please enter the high"));
            H[day] = high;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        try {
            int low = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Please enter the low"));
            L[day] = low;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        day++;        

    }       
}
public static void FindAvg(int[] H, int[] L){

    int sumHigh = 0;
    int avgHigh;

    int sumLow = 0;
    int avgLow;

    for(int i : H)
        sumHigh += i;
    avgHigh = sumHigh/H.length;

    for(int i : L)
        sumLow += i;
    avgLow = sumLow/L.length;

    System.out.println("The average for the high is: " + avgHigh);
    System.out.println("The average for the low is: " + avgLow);
}
public static void Highest(int[] H, int[] L)
{
    int highestHigh = -1000;
    int dayHigh = 0;

    int highestLow = -1000;
    int dayLow = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        if(H[i] > highestHigh && H[i] != 510)
        {
            highestHigh = H[i];
            dayHigh = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "The highest high is: " + highestHigh + " degrees." + "\n" +
            "This temperature was recorded on day: " + dayHigh);    

    for(int i = 0; i < L.length; i++)
    {
        if(L[i] > highestLow && L[i] != 510)
        {
            highestLow = L[i];
            dayLow = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "The highest low is: " + highestLow + " degrees." + "\n" +
            "This temperature was recorded on day: " + dayLow);
}

public static void Lowest(int[] H, int[] L)
{

    int lowestHigh = 1000;
    int dayHigh = 0;

    int lowestLow = 1000;
    int dayLow = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        if(H[i] < lowestHigh)
        {
            lowestHigh = H[i];
            dayHigh = i;    
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "The lowest high is: " + lowestHigh + " degrees." + "\n" +
            "This temperature was recorded on day: " + dayHigh);

    for(int i = 0; i < L.length; i++)
    {
        if(L[i] < lowestLow)
        {
            lowestLow = L[i];
            dayLow = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "The lowest low is: " + lowestLow + " degrees." + "\n" +
            "This temperature was recorded on day: " + dayLow); 
}

public void HighestOrdered(int[] H)
{

}
}
```

Comment: Make a copy of the array and sort that. In a second array you can keep track of the indices, i.e. make the same swaps as in the main array.

Comment: How to sort without sorting

Comment: When you say "without sorting" do you mean: (1) you need to preserve the original ordering information (ie `[56, 45, 67, 41, 59, 70]`), but that making a copy of this and sorting that would be OK; or (2) this is an assignment for some class and sorting is forbidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example to show how this can be done. Only the auxiliary `index` array is sorted, the original `temp` array is not changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int [] temp = {56, 45, 67, 41, 59, 70};

    Integer [] index = new Integer[temp.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
        index[i] = i;
    }

    Arrays.sort(index, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            return temp[a] - temp[b];
        }
    });

    for (Integer i : index) {
        System.out.printf("temp %d on day %d%n", temp[i], i);
    }

}
```

This gives the output:

```
temp 41 on day 3
temp 45 on day 1
temp 56 on day 0
temp 59 on day 4
temp 67 on day 2
temp 70 on day 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.

From your array, create a sorted Map, say

`Map<Integer,Integer> mymap = new  TreeMap<Integer,Integer>`.

You will use temp for the key and the day for the value.  e.g., from your example data,

`myMap.put(56,1);
myMap.put(45,2);`

(Note - in the real code you'd iterate over the array to put the values.)

Then you can iterate over the keys and values (or the entries) in myMap.

Comment: If you use the temperature as key, you should be aware that if two days have the same temperature only the last one will be present in the `Map`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your current array, you can create an object array with each object having two elements: the day and the corresponding temperature.

Sort this array by the temperature value and then print it.